# Django raising exception when I run syncdb

Tags: python, mysql, django

When I run `python manage.py syncdb` in my project, I get the following exception. (I deleted most of the text, because it won't help finding the error anyway.)

```
(...)
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 21: ordinal
 not in range(128)
```

This error will appear in any of my projects in which I use MySQL. If I use SQLite, this problem won't appear. I tested creating the database `teste` with both `latin1` and `utf-8` collations. These are my database settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'teste',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

This was working before, when I was working from a different computer, but not in this one. I installed everything that was necessary for the project to run.

Even getting this tutorial to work with MySQL will raise that exception: http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart.html

Comment: Are you loading fixtures or is this purely during the setup of the tables? My first suggestion would be to reinstall: apt-get install python-mysqldb (not sure if you have apt-get since you didn't say what system you're on).

Comment: @paperreduction I'm using Windows. It is during the setup of the tables.

Comment: In python shell do `import MySQLdb` Do you receive any errors?

Comment: When I used `import MySQLdb`, I got an error saying `ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 nÒo Ú um aplicativo Win32 vßlido.` That, in Portuguese, made me realize I had installed the 32 bits version. I installed the 64 bits version and it worked.

Comment: in command line execute python, what version is that 3.x or 2.x?

Comment: have you read MySQL notes regarding how to use MySQL with django? especially notes on encoding:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#creating-your-database